# PostgreSQL issue (different result in source code and in PgAdmin)

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I faced with interesting case. There are worker service and web service in my application. The job entity status (enum in the source code and integer in the database) is changed in worker service (in the background). There is the endpoint in the web service that returns some info including job status. I assigned breakpoint and discovered that the status is different from the status in PgAdmin. I thought the reason was in Dapper. But I tried simple DataReader and the behavour was the same. In summary the readonly query result in PgAdmin and runtime (C#, .NET Core) are different at the same time moment. I am really struggling here. I read about MVCC in PostgreSQL. Maybe it is because of it. But I am not sure.

Key points are quite simple:

1 - status is changed in TransactionScope with ReadCommited isolation level by update SQL query with using Dapper
2 - status is read by simple select query (not in TransactionScope) by means of Dapper / DataReader (no matter)
3 - status is got in PgAdmin by simple select query

Summary: step 2 status not equals to step 3 status

Any thoughts?